# Creating dynamic HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a project, and am required to build HTML code dynamically.

I've got this code in `main.js`:

```
function main() {
    this.dashboard = new Layer("dashboard");
    this.dashboard.addText("Hello, World!");

    this.newLayer = new Layer("somelayer");
    this.anotherLayer = new Layer("somenewlayer");
    this.newLayer.addText('testing...');
    this.newLayer.addLayer(anotherLayer);

    this.dashboard.addLayer(newLayer);

    this.dashboard.update();

    $("#wrapper").html('');
    $("#wrapper").append(this.dashboard.getElement());
}
```

The function main is called once the body is loaded.

I also have a `layer.js` file with the following code:

```
function Layer(id) {
    this.id = id;
    this.children = [];
    this.el = null;
}

Layer.prototype.addText = function(text) {
    this.children.push(text);
}

Layer.prototype.addLayer = function(l) {
    this.children.push(l);
}

Layer.prototype.getElement = function() {
    return this.el;
}

Layer.prototype.update = function() {
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
    this.el.className += " layer";
    for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
        child = this.children[i];
        alert('child (' + child + ') is...');
        if(typeof child === 'string') {
            alert('...a string');
            txt = document.createTextNode(child); 
            this.el.appendChild(txt);
        } else {
            alert('...not a string');
            child.update();
            this.el.appendChild(child.getElement());
        }

        alert('um kyankst');
    }
}
```

This is used, so that I can dynamically create layers and add text, or more layers to them. After I call update, it should convert it into HTML.

Using the following HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/styles.css".>
        <script src="scripts/jQuery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/layer.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload=main()>
        <div id="wrapper"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I get nearly the result I am looking for--a DIV, and inside it there is some text saying "Hello, World", and then another DIV.

However, inside the other DIV I have added the text 'testing...' and another layer/DIV, but it doesn't seem to be showing up.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Have you considered using a templating library?

https://garann.github.io/template-chooser/

Comment: The elements which I would like to create in the future will be custom elements such as hamburger link elements, tabbed menu elements etc. So for the project I'm working on I cannot do it like that because it needs to be simple like: addTabbedMenu(['page1','page2'], etc. etc.)

Comment: I appreciate that I am not answering the question you have specifically asked, but by using MVC and a templating library you can make all of these things into simple components which you can use in exactly the way you have described, it seems like you are reinventing much of the functionality offered by many of these frameworks. In an MV* example you would create a TabbedMenuView and pass it the target element and data

Comment: Ok, I will look into it, and see if they are useful.

Comment: It might help, the downside is that there will be a period of time where you have to learn those new technologies, if your requirement is a small one then your homebrew approach might be just fine (if it works then who is to say it's wrong afterall), however if this is a large application, you might start to get growing pains fairly quickly without a framework in place

Comment: It's not too much, and a lot of it seems very specific to this project. I'm looking it up now.

Comment: This might help you out? https://jsfiddle.net/byh3qpn8/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114370/discussion-between-yoda-and-david-callanan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `Layer.prototype.update` function make `child` a local variable:

Change:

```
child = this.children[i];
```

...to:

```
var child = this.children[i];
```

Without a `var`, `let`, or `const`, and since the code is not under `use strict` rules, the variable `child` is assumed under global scope. And being under global scope, the value bleeds over from one `update` method execution to another.

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/fiveyayevu/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

I have try to create child nodes inside nesting object. i hope you'll find looking for

```
<script>
    function Layer(id,tagName){
        var scope = this;
        this.tagName = tagName||"div";
        this.elem = false;
        this.children = [];
        this.create = function(id){
            this.elem = document.createElement("div");
            id = id||"";/*you can use generated unique identifyer in here if you want*/
            this.elem.id = id;
        }

        this.addText = function(text){
            text = text||"";
            this.elem.innerHTML = text;
            return this;
        }
        this.addChilds = function(data){
            if(data){
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    var child = new Layer(data[i].id,data[i].tagName).addText(data[i].text);
                    scope.children.push(child); /*to see Layers in console*/
                    scope.elem.appendChild(child.elem);
                }
            }
            return this;
        }
        this.appendTo = function(id){
            document.getElementById(id).appendChild(this.elem);
            return this;
        }
        this.create(id);
    }

    function start(){
        var dashboard = new Layer("dashboard").addText("deneme").addChilds([
            {id:"somelayer",text:"somelayer text",tagName:"div"},
            {id:"somelayer2",text:"somelayer2 text",tagName:"div"}
        ]);
        dashboard.appendTo("wrapper");
    }
    </script>

    <body onLoad="start()">

    <div id="wrapper">
        here is a content for no javascript users
    </div>

    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but not exactly what I was trying to do. Might help me in the future though.